# html5 basic paint tool

Tags: html, canvas, paint

I'm new to html5. And I'm trying to create a basic painting tool.

What I want to do in this tool is to have one or more shapes(maybe overlapping) and to paint the shapes without getting the colors overlapped. If a circle is drawn inside a rectangle and if I start coloring the circle, the rectangle should not be painted even if the mouse is dragged over it unless the dragging starts inside it.

To achieve this should I use multiple canvases or shapes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you need to program in the idea of keeping track of separate shapes. If you haven't already done that see [here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) for a tutorial.

I imagine your shapes will all be kept as images or in-memory canvases themselves. I'm not sure how else you can do it.

There are a million ways you could do this, here's one:

When you *start* your drawing operation you need to detect which shape you're on. Then you draw that shape to an in-memory canvas and switch that temporary canvas' globalcompositeoperation to `source-atop`. This will make sure the paint can only paint in the already opaque regions of that shape (if that's your intent here, which it seems to be).

All while you are painting you will want to update the temporary canvas and redraw the main canvas constantly. While you are redrawing the main canvas, instead of painting that shape's image file you'll want to paint the temporary canvas (if you use canvases to keep the shapes you can just update those in real time).

If you are not using temporary canvases for each shape, when you *stop* the drawing operation you are gonna have to update the image associated with the shape to complete the operation.

---

Using an in-memory canvas (not added to the DOM) for every shape (that is the size of the shape and no larger) will make coding things slightly easier and might not be that bad on performance. I'd give it a try with 100 and 1000 (or more) in-memory canvases on your targeted platforms to see though.

The alternative is to use one in-memory canvas and have an HTMLImageElement (png) that represents every shape, but using the `canvas.toImageURL` function can be a bit of a performance hit in itself. I'd try both methods to see which works best in your case. If the shape count is small enough, it probably doesn't matter which.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It made most of my doubts clear.  I went through the tutorial you mentioned as well.

I agree with having an HTMLImageElement (png) inside an in-memory canvas. For an example we all have colored in coloring books which will have images drawn using strokes/outlines (Lets think about an apple). We color the apple in red the leaf in green and the background or the surrounding area of the apple in a another color. If there's png file which has an apple outlined without fill inside or outside, is there a way to detect the outline and draw the same as a shape in canvas.

Comment: you mean, if you have an outline of a shape, is it easily possible to draw the shape as if it were filled? Sadly that's pretty complex to do...

Comment: Yes, but I need the outline of the shape too. Image's pixels can be read using `getImageData()` and can be drawn back to the canvas. So a png with an outline of a shape should be able to write back to canvas, at the same time as a shape or a canvas itself so that it can be painted using the brush tool.

Comment: I want to achieve almost the same thing as a coloring book. But the objects/shapes to be colored need to be able to load as png or anything which makes it easy.

Comment: well I can think of one possibility. If you're able to manipualte the images beforehand you could fill the center of the apple with almost fully transparent white. As long as its 99.9% transparent the methods discussed ought to work and at the same time appear to the user as if the shape is empty.

Comment: Wow thanks for the positive reply. That's so great. So there's a possibility to read an image and write it back to the canvas as a shape. Will try with the transparent fill as you've advised. But that's the part which I need help. I've tried it already without the transparent fill but it doesn't display anything.